# Wix Bootstrapper check for Net 4.5.2 & then downloads it also checking windows version

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I'm trying to create a wix application that checks for windows install version and downloads the appropriate .net version. It should also check for the windows version.

I've created a .msi with a wix 3.0 project that checks for the appropriate windows version.

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" After="InstallValidate"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" Property="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />  <Condition Message="Your version of Windows is too low">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT <= 602)]]>
</Condition>
```

And I've create a burn bootstrapper that downloads .net 4.5.1 and downloads it if it's not installed.

```
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Web"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="programName" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)SetupProject1/bin/Release/programNameInstaller.msi"/>
    </Chain>
```

I want to combine these two projects somehow, because apparently this doesn't function together for some reason. I'd like the windows version to be checked first if possible so that .net version doesn't download if the user isn't running windows that is high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've gotten this figured out. Here is the finished version. (as of now) You will also need to install the dependencies for WixNetFxExtension.dll and WixBalExtension and I believe also WixUtilExtension

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">


  <Bundle Name="MyProgramInstaller" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="myCompany" UpgradeCode="18b18295-d4a1-4174-99ad-f82f6ca4f7ff">

<!-- checking here for anything over windows 7  you can change this value using the following chart -->
<!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/operating-system-property-values -->
    <bal:Condition Message="This application requires Windows 7 or higher to run.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 601)]]>
    </bal:Condition>

<!-- here's the license statement, would suggest you update this to something more useful. -->
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    
   
  <Chain>
    <!-- here's the .net download installer you can change this using the following chart -->
    <!-- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Web"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="myProgram" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)SetupProject1/bin/Release/myProgramInstaller.msi"/>
  </Chain>

    
    
 </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Note: ["Support for .NET Framework 4.5.1 on all operating systems ended on January 12, 2016."](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework) Many admins don't look too kindly on installers that put versions of software on their systems that the vendor no longer supports.

Comment: This was a requirement from my company who is supporting many old machines, some of which... are still running less than 4.5.  We are planning on updating them to windows 7 this year, (which is why I'm asking for both of these things which seem counterintuitive) but until then I have to get a patch installer running on their machines that functions (some of which from what I've seen are still XP). Also if the machine is running higher than 4.5.1 the install shouldn't happen (at least in all my tests). =)